# Prove that four vectors of the three dimensional Euclidean space are always linearly dependant.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Could anyone check my proof?

Statement: Prove that four vectors of the three dimensional Euclidean space are always linearly dependant.

Proof: A group of vectors are linear dependent if their determinant is zero. Suppose we have three  linearly independent vectors,$\textbf{u},\textbf{v},\textbf{w}$, in $\Bbb{R}^3$. Now consider the subspace $(a,b,c,0)$ of $\Bbb{R}^4$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$. We map the three vectors to that subspace. If we add another vector $\textbf{x}$ to $(a,b,c,0)$, which is the same as adding another vector to $\Bbb{R}^3$, we see that the determinant of the four vectors is equal to zero. Therefore, four vectors in three dimensional Euclidean space are always linearly dependent.

Proof(Attempt again):Suppose we have four linear independent vectors,$\textbf{u},\textbf{v},\textbf{w}$ and $\textbf{x}$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$. Then $a_{1}\textbf{u}+a_{2}\textbf{v}+a_{3}\textbf{w}+a_{4}\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ only when $a_{1}=a_{2}=a_{3}=a_{4}=0$.
However,
\begin{bmatrix}u_{x} & v_{x} & w_{x} & x_{x}\\u_{y} & v_{y} & w_{y} & x_{y}\\u_{z} & v_{z} & w_{z} & x_{z}\end{bmatrix}
becomes
\begin{bmatrix}u_{x} & v_{x} & w_{x} & x_{x}\\0& v'_{y} & w'_{y} & x'_{y}\\0 & 0 & w'_{z} & x'_{z}\end{bmatrix}
by carrying out row operations.

Assuming that the vectors are not zero vectors this shows that there is another non-zero solution for $a_4$ other than zero which is $\frac{-w'_{z}}{x'_{z}}$.
Therefore any four vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Your first sentence only makes sense if you have $n$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$. I can certainly have $2$ or $4$ linearly dependent vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.  You have an artifical ruse to view the four vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ in $\Bbb R^4$. What do you do with $2$ vectors in $\Bbb R^3$?  ... So what precisely is the (precise) statement you're trying to prove? Oh, the title. Please incorporate it into the body of the text, as well. My question now is: What is your definition of linear dependence? Surely it's not with determinants.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about determinants does not make sense too much since one needs a square matrix to start with and four $3-dimensional$ vectors will not give a square matrix.
However, you can work with a similar argument. If you have four linearly independent vectors, that means any three of them are also linearly independent, say $a,b,c$.
Then if you take the vector on your basis you didn't include for those three vectors, it can be obtained by $a,b,c$.
I will leave the details of the proof/arguments to you.

Comment: Could you check my reattempt? Thank you!

Comment: @KhantRain It's correct but needs a few more arguments. If you just plug in $\frac{-w'_z}{x'_z}$ for $a_4$, then only the z component is zero. However, you need a zero vector. So try changing the coefficients $a_1, a_2 and a_3$, it will probably be easier.

Answer (score 0):

To prove linearly independent we  must find $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$a(x_1,y_1,z_1)+b(x_2,y_2,z_2)+c(x_3,y_3,z_3)+d(x_4,y_4,z_4)=0$$ turn into system equatuios
$$\begin{cases}ax_1+bx_2+cx_3+dx_4=0 \\ ay_1+by_2+cy_3+dy_4 = 0\\az_1+bz_2+cz_3+dz_4=0 \\ \end{cases}$$ now note to the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4\\y_1 & y_2& y_3&y_4 \\z_1 &z_2 & z_3 &z_4\end{bmatrix}$$ rank of this matrix at least is 3 not 4